# glDrawPixels in opengl or jogl

Tags: opengl, jogl, gldrawpixels

I have a file in i j r g b format, where i and j are pixel coordinates and r,g,b are colour values ranging from 0-255.
I have scanned them from the file in  a single array(in row major order) but my draw pixel is not working as expected. Please help me out here. Do give the code also ..

Comment: Could you specify "not working as expected"? What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: <quote>Do give the code also</quote>  That's not how things work around here.  Instead, you show the code you're having problems with, explain what your problem is, and we show you how to fix it and/or explain what you need to do differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure what your problem is since you don't explain it and you don't show your code, however, there is no ijrgb format in OpenGL. So you'll have to convert your data to a format that *is* supported (say, rgb, e.g.).